# Access Vuex $store.getters in component method()

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to populate a dropdown Asynchronously (https://vuetifyjs.com/components/selects) using Vuex and Vuetify for a search box. My problem is that I cannot access the $store using the method(), only computed() of course.

Here are my getters/state:

```
loadedTours:Array[9]
0:Object
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
4:Object
5:Object
6:Object
7:Object
8:Object
9:Object
```

which can be returned using v-for from the computed()

```
tours () {
    return this.$store.getters.loadedTours
},
```

Here is a method() that works only if the list is in the data():

```
methods: {
    querySelections (v) {
        this.loading = true
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.items = this.tours.filter(e => {
                    return (e || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((v || '').toLowerCase()) > -1
                })
            this.loading = false
        }, 500)
    }
}
```

The result should return the tour titles listed in each object.

Current solution:

added created():

```
created () {
    this.loadedTours = this.$store.getters.loadedTours
},
```

changed method() to:

```
querySelections (v) {
    let that = this; 
    setTimeout(() => {
        that.items = that.loadedTours
    }, 500)
}
```

Removed the arrow function at the data property.

Now need to return the tourTitle, then filter by the input.

Comment: So which one is working and which one isn't?

Comment: @samayo if you look at the link, the last example on that page, that is working fine, but their data is in the data() area where my data stored in Vuex. How would I go about using their method and my store?

Comment: use `created(){}` method in which you can do `this.loadedTours = this.$store.getters.loadedTours` then you can use `this.loadedTours` inside your `querySelections` but you need to create an empty val inside your data(){} for `loadedTours`

Comment: okay so I added:
`created(){
      this.loadedTours = this.$store.getters.loadedTours
    },`
and
`
loadedToursA: ""
`
and the query is now
`this.items = this.loadedToursA.filter(e => {`

Comment: Check my answer, you can not use `this.` inside arrow functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what I mentioned in the comments, your main error is probably because you are using `this` inside the arrow function, because `this` will not refer to the right (vuejs) context,

From the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data):

> Note that you should not use an arrow function with the data property (e.g. data: () => { return { a: this.myProp }}). The reason is arrow functions bind the parent context, so this will not be the Vue instance as you expect and this.myProp will be undefined.

instead do something like this:

```
  let that = this; 
  setTimeout(() => callback(that.name), 15);
```

Now, `that` will refer to use vuejs `this` object

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160720/discussion-on-answer-by-samayo-access-vuex-store-getters-in-component-method).